# Bootstrap table don't use right value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap, jquery and bootstrap-table 
When i go to a tab , i call an js function.

In this function i init a bootstrap-table who use a param.  First time i go to the tab, that work fine.

If i got to another tab, to change the param. when i come back to the tab, it's the old value of the param who are used.

If first time memberId = 5...
I go to another tab... memberId is 2...
but in the boostrapTable that continue to be 5

```
var initMemberPayment = function initMemberPaymentTable() {
    var memberId = $("#memberId").val();
    $("#memberPaymentTableResult").bootstrapTable({
        url: getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/payments",
     ...
     });
     ...
};
```

Comment: when you go to another tab, what code changes the #memberId?

Comment: a click on the value... if i put an alert after memberId, i see the new value... but bootstrap-table continue to use old value... i read a few second ago they seem to have a refresh function. So i don't really understand how to to do difference between call to be able to call refresh after the first one

Comment: try ditching the var memberId and just put $("#memberId").val() in the string concatenation

Comment: that change nothing

Comment: can you paste the code that changes the memberId?

Comment: useless, nothing to do $("#memberId").val("55");